# Parse json output in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
{
        "set" : "rs01",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:05:04Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "myserver1:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 608144,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1469650746, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-27T20:19:06Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1469653499, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:04:59Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "myserver3.uu.server.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 11,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1469650746, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-27T20:19:06Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:05:03Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:05:03Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing to: myserver1:27017",
                        "syncingTo" : "myserver1:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "myserver2.uu.server.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:05:03Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-27T21:03:13Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Question:

1) How can I parse this json output in python?

2) I would like to extract "health" : 1 and "state" : 1, from the output.

Comment: Python has [a `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) in the standard library. Have you tried it?

Comment: That does not look like json, what are `ISODate` and `Timestamp`?

Comment: Where is the  data from? Looks like BSON.

Comment: Yes, looks like a document from MongoDB